# Не выводится одиночная запись

Tags: php, wordpress

есть сайт, на котором используется плагин Carbon fields.
Была создан шаблон для рубрики "Блог"(id = 4), созданы две тестовые записи. При переходе по ссылке на запись не выводится контент, только print_r(130)

**Шаблон рубрики Блог(category-blog.php) :**

```
    <?php
get_header();
get_template_part('template-parts/heder_page');
get_template_part('template-parts/blog');
get_template_part('template-parts/bread');
?>
    <section class="blog-page">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="custom-heading">
                        <h2>Блог</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">


                <?php
                global $post;

                $myposts = get_posts( [
                    'posts_per_page' => 6,
                    'category' => 4,
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                ] );

                foreach( $myposts as $post ){
                    setup_postdata( $post );
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="article">
                            <p class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                            <div class="content">
                                <?
                                the_excerpt();
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="more">Читать полностью</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
<?php
get_template_part('template-parts/form');
get_footer();
```

**Шаблон записи single.php :**

```
    <?php
get_header();
get_template_part('template-parts/heder_page');
get_template_part('template-parts/bread');
if(in_category(4)) {
print_r(130);
    if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            the_title();
            the_content();
        endwhile;
    endif;
} else {
    get_template_part('template-parts/about_text');
    get_template_part('template-parts/what_in');
    get_template_part('template-parts/steps');

}
get_template_part('template-parts/form');
get_footer();
?>
```

**Возможно влияет Carbon fields, есть файл по пути inc/carbon-fields/include-fields.php :**

```
        // Single Товар, Новость
    add_action( 'carbon_fields_register_fields', 'type_post_services' );
    function type_post_services() {
        $Container = new Fields_Post_And_Hide_Template('post_meta', 'Настройки страницы', 'services', 'single.php');
        $Container->heder_page();
        $Container->about_text();
        $Container->what_in();
        $Container->steps();
        return $Container;
    }
```

[image: страница рубрики Блог]
[image: результат перехода по ссылке записи]

Comment: У Вас там `the_post();` два раза в цикле. И при чем здесь Carbon Fields, если в приведенном коде он никак не фигурирует?

Comment: убрал лишний the_post(); добавил в описание про carbon-filelds, но это лишь мое предположение...

Comment: @Anario Дебажьте. Проверьте попадаете ли вы в цикл `while (have_posts())`.  Я не знаю как устроен вордпресс, но интуитивно на странице записи не будет вложенных постов. Там будет текущая запись. Если сделать `the_title()` вне цикла, выведет текущий заголовок?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин действительно, ваш совет помог! вне цикла в single.php выводится the_title() и the_content()

Answer (score 0):

В single.php
Нужно сразу выводить the_title(); the_content(); и остальные данные одиночной записи
Повторный цикл для вывода оказался не нужен